# what is the different between configuration files under /etc/hadoop/conf and /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.HDFS and /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.YARN

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have cloudera 5.7, I have Cloudera Manager too.

under the directory /etc/hadoop, I saw three sub-directories.
   /etc/hadoop/conf
   /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.HDFS/
   /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.YARN/

the hadoop-env.sh in ../conf/ is different from ../conf.cloudera.HDFS/..
the core-site.xml in ../conf/ is different from ../conf.cloudera.HDFS/.. as well.

the hadoop-env.sh in ../conf/ has settings on YARN, while the one under../conf.cloudera.HDFS doesn't has it.

and the one in ../conf.cloudera.HDFS/.. has the settings for Namenode, datanodes, etc.

I have CM installed, I am wondering if these configuration files are really in use?

If yes, and I need to change some environment variables, should I change all of these hadoop-env.sh? and copy it to the other nodes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudera Manager handle settings for you. If you edit the settings files manually, it will erase by CM.
If you want make some change, do it by CM.

Comment: Thank you very much @Xire. I have one more question since CM handles all the settings, the configurations files are not in use in the /etc/hadoop path, why I have 3 configuration paths in /etc/hadoop? what is the difference between them? Thanks again.

Comment: Did you install CDH with CM ?

Comment: /etc/hadoop/conf is symbolic link to /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn
/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn is the conf deploy by CM for YARN service. It's the same for HDFS

Comment: Thanks again@Xire, forgive me if my question is too dumb. I know CM has a centralized conf databbase . I am a little bit confused for  " /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn is the conf deploy by CM for YARN service," I checked the yarn log4j.properties from CM is different from /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/log4j.properties. and if I made any changes on yarn log4j.properties from CM, it didn't show up under /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/log4j.properties.

Comment: Connect you with ssh on one of your node and execute this line `sudo alternatives --display hadoop-conf`. You will see that conf dir is one of the directory you mention.

Do you redeploy conf and restart your service after editing ?

Comment: Thank you so much @Xire. I did restart the related service but I didn't do the redeploy. I will redeploy it and see how it looks like. One more dumb question, I want to double check this, since I have CM installed, there is no way to manually change the conf, everything must go thru CM, but CM will 'save' the settings under the sudo alternatives --display hadoop-conf path, right? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes that's right but only for HDFS & Yarn, other services are in other repository.

Comment: @sparkmeow if it resolv don't forget to tag your question